# How to retrieve the children's children's data?

Tags: firebase, android-recyclerview

I wonder if there is anyway that I can write a constructor for the image below.
I just need to retrieve the data of schoolname, schoolcode, and schoollocation.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ER2P.png)

Comment: Please write a minimal, specific and varifiable question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: My question is: Is there any way that I can write a constructor with its children so that I can retrieve the children's children's data.

Answer (score 0):

#### [firebase.database.DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot)

> A DataSnapshot contains data from a Database location.
>
> Any time you read data from the Database, you receive the data as a
> DataSnapshot. A DataSnapshot is passed to the event callbacks you
> attach with on() or once(). You can extract the contents of the
> snapshot as a JavaScript object by calling the val() method.
> Alternatively, you can traverse into the snapshot by calling child()
> to return child snapshots (which you could then call val() on).
>
> A DataSnapshot is an efficiently generated, immutable copy of the data
> at a Database location. It cannot be modified and will never change
> (to modify data, you always call the set() method on a Reference
> directly).